# Switching databases in Rails/Postgres is causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to setup a testing environment where I can simulate writing to a master database and reading from a slave database. Currently I have a parent model with a `before_save` and `after_save` callback that switches to slave and back to master.

I'm running into this error though `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed: ROLLBACK`

**application_record.rb**

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.abstract_class = true

  before_save :switch_to_master
  after_save :switch_to_slave

  def switch_to_slave
    config = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "database.yml"))[Rails.env.to_s]
    ApplicationRecord.establish_connection(config)
  end

  def switch_to_master
    config = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "database_master.yml"))[Rails.env.to_s]
    ApplicationRecord.establish_connection(config)
  end

end
```

**master_slave_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class MasterSlaveTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_one
    @user = users(:john)

    @user.update(last_name: 'Change')
    @user.update(last_name: 'Change')


    assert "Change", @user.reload.last_name
  end

end
```

**database.yml**

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: autobrain_test_slave
  host: localhost
```

**database_master.yml**

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: autobrain_test
  host: localhost
```

Comment: does your other database have all the migrations and schema definition as in the master

Comment: @sa77 yes it does